# "Cannot resolve directory" WebStorm warning for create-react-app

Tags: webstorm, create-react-app

When I use create-react-app's `%PUBLIC_URL%` token in my root html file, WebStorm complains that it can't resolve the url it is part of.

The error is: *Cannot resolve directory '%PUBLIC_URL'*

[image: "Cannot resolve directory" warning]

In this case the warning is spurious: it works as intended in development and production. The `%PUBLIC_URL%` token maps to the location of the `public/` directory, which I have marked as the resource root.

I can suppress the warning for the entire file with a `<!--suppress HtmlUnknownTarget -->` directive, but that means WebStorm won't check that urls are valid. This comment also appears in the final html output, which is sort of undesirable too.

Can I get WebStorm to understand what `%PUBLIC_URL%` means in the context of a create-react-app instance?

Comment: You can't:( Suppressing the warning is the only way to get rid of the issue

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a perfect solution but you can create a symbolic link in your project root called `%PUBLIC_URL%` that points to the `public` directory.

On Linux:

```
ln -s public/ %PUBLIC_URL%
```

On Windows (I have not tested this so it may not work):

```
mklink /D %PUBLIC_URL% public
```